# Reason to use File Descriptors Linked to stdin Rather than use stdin Directly?

Tags: bash, networking, router, file-descriptor

I have a `bash` script which starts `scp` in following way:

```
echo "${SCP_PASS:-$PASSWORD}" | ( exec 3<&0; scp -qp ${SCP_PORT:+-P$SCP_PORT} -oStrictHostKeyChecking=yes -oPasswordFd=3 $TRANSFER_FILE "$SCP_USER@$SCP_HOST:$SCP_PATH" )
```

What is the point of the `exec 3<&0`? As I understand, it copies the `stdin` to file descriptor `3`. Why is this needed? Why not use `-oPasswordFd=0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit here to redirecting stdin to fd 3 - also PasswordFd does not seem to be an openssh option - seems the scp being run is a wrapper or custom-built - in general though the benefit of providing the password on a separate file descriptor is to keep stdin open for data transfer which btw openssh scp does not support

Comment: @Martin: do you know where your `scp` came from?

Comment: @chicks It is on Junos operating system. In other words it's probably a custom build of `scp`.

Comment: That makes sense - it's possible this custom scp allows input data on stdin

Comment: For Junos questions you'll probably find better answers and less risk of being off-topic on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/